# Merge Azure mp4 blobs via API (Preferred Azure)

Tags: azure, ffmpeg, merge, cloud, scale

I need to join multiple clips in to 1 video file.

I tried doing it on my azure consumption serverless function but with bigger files its very slow and sometimes gives errors

This is part of a bigger orchestrator functon where i create clips, merge them replace audio and upload it the finalized version to my blobstorage.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.